# Converting inline event to addEventListener method

Tags: javascript, audio, addeventlistener

I'm trying to move an inline Javascript event trigger away from the HTML into a separate Javascript file. I'm having difficulty converting this piece of code:

```
 <audio id="audio-source" preload="true" ontimeupdate="document.getElementById('tracktime').innerHTML = Math.floor(this.currentTime)">
```

into an addEventListener method inside my Javascript file. This is what I have so far:

```
 var audioDuration = document.getElementById('tracktime');
 audioDuration.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){
     this.innerHTML = Math.floor(this.currentTime);
 }, false);
```

It's not returning anything in the browser and I see no errors in the console when inspecting via the Chrome dev tools. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning an option to element

`audioDuration.ontimeupdate = function() { ... };`